# Windows sandbox won't open executables. ("You need to install an app for this task")

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-sandbox

I am using the Windows sandbox feature, that comes with Windows Pro and Enterprise systems (Using Hyper-V). It worked for months, but now I always get the same error when I try to run an .exe file. The executable is compiled with the Go compiler and does not need any external dependencies (no .net whatsoever). I tried several different exe files from the internet, and all have the same error pop up.

[image: error screenshot]

I cannot click on yes, as there is no Windows Store in the Sandbox.

Does anyone know, how I could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Sandbox system info:

[image: sandbox system info]

**EDIT:**

After further investigation, I found that this is happening with unsigned apps. I think it wants to install Windows Smart Screen. I could disable that in the Windows Security panel, but I cannot open it (it closes immediately when I open it, just a quick flash in the taskbar).

Comment: Windows Sandbox is a temporary thing. Remove it in Programs and Features, Windows Features, restart the computer, Enable it again and test.

Comment: What architectures were the executables compiled against?

Comment: @John done, sadly still the same error.

Comment: @Ramhound amd64

Comment: If you cannot get it to work, at ll, try a free third-party tool such as Sandboxie, https://sandboxie-plus.com/

Comment: If it did work at one time perhaps do a Windows Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have sandboxie, but my usecase needs a much more isolated sandbox and I just bought Windows Pro for the sandbox feature.

Comment: After further investigation, I found that this is happening with unsigned apps. I think it wants to install Windows Smart Screen. I could disable that in the Windows Security panel, but I cannot open it (it closes immediately when I open it, just a quick flash in the taskbar).

Comment: Okay, I guess I found a workaround. I can disable Smart Screen by changing some registry values.

Comment: That's odd -- the whole purpose of a sandbox is to test untrusted apps, and it simply refuses to do so with a new app. The issue with Windows Smart Screen is that it is cloud based, and if this app is not found (either because it was newly created by the user, or by a third party), then how will it handle that? One might as well just submit the app to VirusTotal.

Comment: Yes @DrMoishePippik, I don't understand it either. The Windows Sandbox is lacking a lot of features imo. They should allow ways to pre-install dependencies like the Windows Terminal, .NET, Winget, VS Code, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens with unsigned executables. It wants to install Windows Smartscreen. You can disable Windows Smartscreen with this powershell script:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" -Name "EnableSmartScreen" -Type DWord -Value 0
If (!(Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter")) {
    New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter" -Force | Out-Null
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\PhishingFilter" -Name "EnabledV9" -Type DWord -Value 0
```

This script could also be added to the `LogonCommand` of the Sandbox configuration.